# How to pass several outputs of one script into another script

Tags: shell, zsh

I've got a zsh function that separates list of given arguments into two lines, separated with spaces:

```
function foo() {
    echo "a b c";
    echo "d e f";
}

$foo
a b c 
d e f
```

I'd like to pass the output into another function so that it recognizes is as exactly two arguments.

```
function bar() {
    for i in "$@"
    do
        echo $i;
    done
}
```

Now it works as:

```
$ bar $(foo)
a
b
c
...
```

What I would like to have

```
$ bar $(foo)
a b c
d e f
```

I've tried to echo the resulting lines in "quotes" and in "'double quotes'" but that has no result.

(zsh 5.0.5 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0))

---

Update: used the `bar "$(foo)"` syntax, now it seems to be just one argument:

```
function bar() {
    echo "\$1=";
    echo $1;
    echo "\$2=";
    echo $2;
}

$ bar "$(foo)"
$1=
a b c
d e f
$2=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some of `zsh`'s fancier parameter expansion features to split the output from `foo` into separate words.

```
foo () {
    echo "a b c"
    echo "d e f"
}

bar () {

    printf "Arg: %s\n" "$@"
}

bar "${(f):-$(foo)}"
```

A breakdown of what's going on:

1. `$(foo)` evaluates to a single string containing an embedded newline. (Caveat: any *trailing* newlines will be discarded; that shouldn't be an issue, though.)
2. `${:-whatever}` expands to the string following `:-`. It's essentially the default value expansion, but you omit the name of the parameter to expand, so it *always* expands to the default. It seems pointless, but it allows us to apply parameter expansion flags to arbitrary text (such as the command substitution in step 1)
3. `${(f)...}` splits the string into multiple words on newlines.

Together, the single expansion acts something like:

```
lines=()
while read line; do
    lines+=( $line )
done < <(foo)

bar $lines[@]
```

---

Or, define `bar` as

```
bar () {
    printf "Arg: %s\n" "${(f)1}"
}
```

to get the same result with

```
bar "$(foo)"
```

(the quotes, at least, remain necessary).

Comment: That's great, thank you for the explanation. Took me several reads to understand )) I'll be able to try it tomorrow. Do I understand it right that this syntax allows me to make an array of arguments out of any string (like with `xargs`)? Say, I've got `$paths="path1 path2 "path 3"`. So `"${(f):-$paths}"` breaks into three lines, right?"

Comment: Not quote. That would be true with `paths=$'path1\npath2\npath 3'`. As you wrote, it would be more difficult to split, since embedded quotes are simply literal characters in the string, rather than "nesting" to provide structure.